# Discord.js If Member Highest Role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hey guys I have an issue I want to do a code that check member highest role when the member roles changes
and then change the member nickname according to his roles.

My Code(**not working**):

```
        client.on("message", message => {
          if(message.member.roles.highest.name === 'Admin')
          message.member.setNickname('Admin')
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide us the error message?

Answer (score 1):

**Discord JS V12**

```
GuildMember.roles.highest
```

**Discord JS V11**

```
GuildMember.highestRole
```

**Code:**

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.guildMember.roles.highest.name === 'Admin')
  message.member.setNickname('Admin')
});
```